# How can I convert scraped data from a Wikipedia table into a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

I'm a beginner when it comes to web scraping and Python in general, so any help is appreciated. As the title suggests, I'm trying to take a table from Wikipedia ([this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GameCube_games)) and import it's columned data into a list of dictionaries.

Something like this:

```
games = [
    {"title": "Super Mario Sunshine", "developer": "Nintendo EAD", "publisher": "Nintendo"},
    {"title": "F-Zero GX", "developer": "Amusement Vision", "publisher": "Nintendo"},
    {"title": "Pikmin", "developer": "Nintendo EAD", "publisher": "Nintendo"},

]
```

(Except where there's a key and value for each of the columns from the original table, not just title, developer and publisher.)

I'm trying to make the keys and values as accessible as possible for use with various functions in my program.

I have tried using this code (not mine):

```
import pandas as pd
import wikipedia as wp
html = wp.page("List_of_GameCube_games").html().encode("UTF-8")
try:
    df = pd.read_html(html)[1]  # Try 2nd table first as most pages contain contents table first
except IndexError:
    df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
print(df.to_string())
```

Which very neatly puts everything I need into a string, I'm just not sure how to write code that will turn each row of data into its own separate dictionary, with keys and values representing the columns in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data from the table into a dictionary use next example:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

cleanup = re.compile(r"(.*)(NA|PAL|JP|AUS|EU)")


df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GameCube_games")[1]
df = df.droplevel(level=0, axis=1).loc[:, :"North America"]
for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace(
        cleanup, lambda g: g.group(1) + " " + g.group(2), regex=True
    )
df.columns = [c.split("[")[0].split("(")[0] for c in df]

d = df.to_dict(orient="records")
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "Title": "4x4 Evo 2",
        "Developer": "Terminal Reality",
        "Publisher": "Universal Interactive",
        "First released": "2002-09-24 NA",
        "Europe / PAL": "Unreleased",
        "Japan": "Unreleased",
        "North America": "September 24, 2002",
    },
    {
        "Title": "18 Wheeler: American Pro Trucker",
        "Developer": "Sega AM2Acclaim Studios Cheltenham",
        "Publisher": "Acclaim Entertainment",
        "First released": "2002-02-20 NA",
        "Europe / PAL": "May 31, 2002",
        "Japan": "September 12, 2002",
        "North America": "February 20, 2002",
    },
    {
        "Title": "1080° Avalanche",
        "Developer": "Nintendo Software Technology",
        "Publisher": "Nintendo",
        "First released": "2003-11-28 PAL",
        "Europe / PAL": "November 28, 2003",
        "Japan": "January 22, 2004",
        "North America": "December 1, 2003",
    },

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the code to work after adding 'import re'. Though my output came out a bit differently. For me, the dictionaries are stretched across many lines as one wall of text, rather than in an organized/separated fashion like you showed above. How would I go about separating the dictionaries in the print statement?

Comment: @DejaLukas You can use `pprint` module. E.g.: `from pprint import pprint;pprint(d)`